# SL5 OOB app - after minimizing, restores to different size

Tags: silverlight-5.0, out-of-browser

I have a Silverlight oob app.  If I click on the icon in the task bar, the app minimizes.
When I click on the icon again, the app restores, but with a different size.
What controls the size the app restores to?
Is there an event I can intercept when the app restores to make sure the app restores to the correct size?

Thanks for any insights....